# More than one enum declaration

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer

There is the quote from the sec. 3.3.1/4 of N3797 working draft:

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of
>   which specifies the same unqualified name,
>
> — exactly one declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration
>   name that is not a typedef name and the other declarations shall all
>   refer to the same variable or enumerator, or all refer to functions
>   and function templates;

We can declare `enum` type name several times in a single declarative region:

```
enum A; // declared first time, the other declaration with the same
        // unqualified name shall all refer to the same variable or enumeration.
enum A; // This and the other declarations shall all refer to the that enumeration
extern int A; // Fail, now enum A is hidden and we can access it
              // via elaborated-type-specifier only
```

I'm confused. Can you explain this behavior? I would like to find corresponding references to the current working draft.

Comment: No [we cannot](http://ideone.com/9foG8J) declare `enum` type name several times. In fact, [we cannot](http://ideone.com/Zh4rI7) even declare it once, the way you show.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But what about _opaque-enum-declaration_ which defined as `enum-key attribute-specifier-seq_opt identifier enum-base_opt`.

Comment: Yours is not it. **7.2/2** An *opaque-enum-declaration* declaring an unscoped enumeration shall not omit the *enum-base*.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Are you sure that you are looking at the same working draft that I specified in my post (N3797 C++14 working draft)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full quote n3797 3.3.1/4 is:

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of which specifies the same unqualified name,
>
> — they shall all refer to the same entity, or all refer to functions and function templates; or
>
> — exactly one declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration name that is not a typedef name
>   and the other declarations shall all refer to the same variable or enumerator, or all refer to functions and function templates; in this case the class name or enumeration name is hidden.

The code you wrote is wrong. See S7.2 for the required syntax, which may be any of these:

```
enum A : int; // declaration (and it is an enumeration name)
enum A : int; // refers to the same entity

enum struct A; // declaration (and it is an enumeration name)
enum struct A; // refers to the same entity

enum A {}; // declaration (and it is an enumeration name)
enum A {}; // refers to the same entity
```

Then the following may occur later in the translation unit.

```
extern int A; // declaration hides enumeration name

void f() {
  A j = A.a; // illegal. A is hidden
  int k = A; // legal
}
```

See n3797 3.3.10/2:

> A class name (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) can be hidden by the name of a variable, data member,
>   function, or enumerator declared in the same scope. If a class or enumeration name and a variable, data member, function, or enumerator are declared in the same scope (in any order) with the same name, the class or enumeration name is hidden wherever the variable, data member, function, or enumerator name is visible.

So the last A hides the earlier ones. Is that what you were asking?

---

Re the question: is the program well-formed? Obviously these are just fragments, and no complete program has been presented, but would it be legal if these were the only references to `A`? My answer is yes. S7.2/6 says:

> An enumeration whose underlying type is fixed is an incomplete type from its point of declaration (3.3.2) to immediately after its enum-base (if any), at which point it becomes a complete type. An enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed is an incomplete type from its point of declaration to immediately after the closing } of its enum-specifier, at which point it becomes a complete type.

So in each of the examples given A is a complete type as shown. The 7.2/3 says:

> An opaque-enum-declaration is either a redeclaration of an enumeration in the current scope or a declaration of a new enumeration. [ Note: An enumeration declared by an opaque-enum-declaration has fixed underlying type and is a complete type. The list of enumerators can be provided in a later redeclaration with an enumspecifier. —end note ] A scoped enumeration shall not be later redeclared as unscoped or with a different underlying type. An unscoped enumeration shall not be later redeclared as scoped and each redeclaration shall include an enum-base specifying the same underlying type as in the original declaration.

So it seems that these declarations can be repeated as long as the attributes and base are the same, but perhaps not once the list of enumerators has been provided.

For the first two it would seem the program is well-formed, but perhaps not for the last.

Comment: Let's assume those `enum`-declarations were actually legal, like `enum class A; enum class A;` or `enum A : int; enum A : int;`. Is the program well-formed then, despite having *not just one* declaration that declares an enumeration name?

Comment: The program is legal as it stands (excluding the illegal assignment). Setting the base type or scope doesn't change that (as long as they refer to the same entity). If you have something more complicated in mind, you probably need to ask a new question.

Comment: `enum A;` is certainly not legal as [Igor Tandetnik](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) also pointed out in comments to the OP. You cannot leave out the enum-base for forward-declarations of unscoped enums. The actual question I have is about the two declarations of an enumeration. 3.3.1/4 says "exactly one declaration shall declare a [...] enumeration name" and here we have two declarations declaring an enumeration name. So the requirement for hiding does not hold as far as I can see.

Comment: @dyp: I disagree. `enum A;` is legal on my reading of n3797 s7.2 _opaque-enum-declaration_. Please show otherwise.

Comment: @dyp: see edit. Better now? To your original question, by my reading the program is well-formed (7.2/3: `is a complete type`) In any case there was no presumption that these code fragments constituted an entire translation unit, let alone a whole program.

Comment: *"by my reading the program is well-formed (7.2/3: is a complete type)"* Hmm I don't quite understand how that quotes relates to the rest.. -- `enum A : int; enum A : int;` are two declarations that declare the same thing. So my question was whether those two declarations count as one for the requirement *exactly one declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration name*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong. Enumerator (enum) is a type, if you write
     `enum A;`
 You are giving a name to this type, but still you don't have any variables. There are two possible ways for declaration.
1. You can write:
`enum A { a, b, c };`
, now you have 3 variables { a, b, c }, their type is enum and the name of the type is A. The second way is:
                `enum NAME; 
NAME var1;
NAME var2;`
You also can have unnamed variables:
`enum { a, b, c };`
This is used when you want names for constants but don't plan to use the type to declare variables, function arguments, etc.

Comment: Seems, you don'r understand me. I would to understand formal c++ language rules. I don't interesting of usability in this question.